# TCP: Почему метод Socket.Send возвращает число записанных байт, а его обертка NetworkStream.Write (например, в TcpClient) - нет?

Tags: c#, сокет

1. Есть *WinAPI*, в нем реализация Berkeley sockets, в частности функция `send()`, которая **возвращает число** отправленных байт.
2. В .NET есть обертка `System.Net.Sockets.Socket`, в ней метод `Socket.Send()`, который вызывает нативный `send()` и также **возвращает это число**.
3. А еще в .NET есть `System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream`, он используется в `TcpClient` и стало быть в `TcpListener`. В этом `NetworkStream` есть метод `NetworkStream.Write()`, который является оберткой для `Socket.Send()`. **И вот этот `NetworkStream.Write()` уже не возвращает число, а возвращает `void`.**

Можно было бы предположить, что внутри `NetworkStream.Write` реализован алгоритм, который вызывает `Socket.Send` несколько раз, и тем самым добивается того, чтобы передались все байты, в таком случае он не должен возвращать число, поскольку в конечном итоге оказываются записаны все байты.

Но открываем исходный код метода `NetworkStream.Write`, и видим, что это не так:

```
        /// <devdoc> 
        ///    <para>
        ///       Writes data to the stream.. 
        ///    </para> 
        /// </devdoc>
        public override void Write(byte[] buffer, int offset, int size) { 
#if DEBUG
            using (GlobalLog.SetThreadKind(ThreadKinds.User | ThreadKinds.Sync)) {
#endif
            if (m_CleanedUp){ 
                throw new ObjectDisposedException(this.GetType().FullName);
            } 
            // 
            // parameter validation
            // 
            if (buffer==null) {
                throw new ArgumentNullException("buffer");
            }
            if (offset<0 || offset>buffer.Length) { 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("offset");
            } 
            if (size<0 || size>buffer.Length-offset) { 
                throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("size");
            } 
            if (!CanWrite) {
                throw new InvalidOperationException(SR.GetString(SR.net_readonlystream));
            }


            Socket chkStreamSocket = m_StreamSocket; 
            if(chkStreamSocket == null) { 
                throw new IOException(SR.GetString(SR.net_io_writefailure, SR.GetString(SR.net_io_connectionclosed)));
            } 

            try {
                //
                // since the socket is in blocking mode this will always complete 
                // after ALL the requested number of bytes was transferred
                // 
                chkStreamSocket.Send(buffer, offset, size, SocketFlags.None); 
            }
            catch (Exception exception) { 
                if (exception is ThreadAbortException || exception is StackOverflowException || exception is OutOfMemoryException) {
                    throw;
                }

                //
                // some sort of error occured on the socket call, 
                // set the SocketException as InnerException and throw 
                //
                throw new IOException(SR.GetString(SR.net_io_writefailure, exception.Message), exception); 
            }
            catch {
                //
                // some sort of error occured on the socket call, 
                // set the SocketException as InnerException and throw
                // 
                throw new IOException(SR.GetString(SR.net_io_writefailure, string.Empty), new Exception(SR.GetString(SR.net_nonClsCompliantException))); 
            }
#if DEBUG 
            }
#endif
        }
```

Что же? Это число просто теряется в `NetworkStream.Write` и вообще никак в нем не задействовано.

Может быть, в самом деле нет смысла его проверять и все байты всегда успешно записываются?
Но кое-кто пишет, что это не всегда так, да и спрашивается зачем тогда `Send` возвращает значение, если оно не нужно?

**Так все-таки, могут ли в поток записаться не все байты? В каком случае?**

Comment: Так вроде ничего не теряется - там даже комментарий есть - сокет в режими блокировки, если будут записаны не все байты - Вы словите exception, нет ?

Comment: @isnullxbh А в каком случае они могут быть не все записаны? Из-за чего? От этого зависит, как я должен обрабатывать этот exception - подключаться к серверу повторно или просто попробовать еще раз.

Comment: Я думаю, Вы и сами сможете легко с этим разобраться - посмотрите, какие типы исключений перехватываются catch'ем: закрылся сокет, буфер стал _null_, поток стал read-_only_ и т.д.

Comment: @isnullxbh Код выше видели? ЛЮБЫЕ перехватываются.

Comment: _Видели_. Теперь предлагаем пересмотреть Вам.

Comment: @isnullxbh Пересмотрел. Написано: `try { ... } catch (Exception exception) { }` Вывод: любые типы исключений перехватываются.

Comment: Еще раз смотрите. Пример: я писал - испорчен буфер - это выявляется до того, как вызывается метод ```Send()```. И после того, как вызывается send - в тело catch'a то загляните.

Comment: В MSDN тоже можете заглянуть.

Answer (score 1):

[`Socket.Send`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/w93yy28a(v=vs.110).aspx) задаёт общий интерфейс для разных типов сокетов, как требующих установления соединения (например, TCP), так и не требующих установления соединения (UDP). В блокирующем режиме при установлении соединения либо будут отправлены все данные, т.е. вернётся заранее известное кол-во байт, либо будет сгенерировано исключение, и тогда о возвращаемом значении вообще не может быть речи. В неблокирующем режиме `Send` может вернуть уже меньшее кол-во байт, чем реально указано аргументом.

[`NetworkStream.Write`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.networkstream.write(v=vs.110).aspx) отправляет данные исключительно в блокирующем режиме. Поэтому либо все данные будут переданы, либо вызовется исключение. Как ранее уже было сказано. Т.о. дублировать в возврате заранее известное число байт особого смысла нет.

Comment: Спасибо, что напомнили про UDP, но вот насчет исключения в блокирующем режиме, вы не знаете в каком именно случае оно может "выброситься"? Пропадание сети, брандмауэр, неполадки с драйвером или что? Просто мне надо знать, как его обрабатывать, что писать в `catch`, грубо говоря. А именно - мне надо знать, должно ли мое приложение в случае исключения просто повторить вызов `NetworkStream.Write` или же оно должно повторно вызывать `Connect`, поскольку подключение разорвано.

Comment: @KG, покажите Ваш код.